# Using Optisystem software for simulation

Tags: installation, usability

I am using Optisystem software to simulate a project and the project browser of the software is inactive or disabled, where I can't access the component properties when creating graphs for report purposes. Can anyone help on that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the user forum at the vendor's site: **http://optiwave.com/forums/**

You won't have any luck posting questions on software usability on [**stackoverflow.com**](http://stackoverflow.com). The site is dedicated to **coding issues**, and other topics tend to get downvoted and sent elsewhere. You may have better luck posting questions like these on another **stack-exchange** site: [**superuser.com**](http://superuser.com).